# Is there a way to use PyInstaller inside another .py file?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

My Problem is the following:
I want to create an script that can create other executables. These new executables have to be standalone, so they don't require any DLL's, etc.
I know this is possible with PyInstaller, but only from console/command line.
So essentially, what I want to do is make a python script that imports pyinstaller, creates another .py-file and uses pyinstaller to compile the new script to a .exe, so people who don't have python installed can use this program.

EDIT: The script itself should only use one file, so it can also be a one-file executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check out [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/), which can be used to do this kind of thing.

> There are three different ways to use cx_Freeze. The first is to use the included cxfreeze script which works well for simple scripts. The second is to create a distutils setup script which can be used for more complicated configuration or to retain the configuration for future use. **The third method involves working directly with the classes and modules used internally by cx_Freeze and should be reserved for complicated scripts or extending or embedding**.

[Source](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/cx_Freeze.html)

Comment: is there a way to use cx_freeze without a setup script?
I want to be able to compile a .py to a .exe without having any sort of python installed...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I highlighted in the passage I quoted. You'd need to grab the source for the module and use it directly.

Comment: can I just do "import cx_Freeze" and then make the main.py simulate the command line arguments? So it returns all the arguments the way they would normally be, but it doesnt parse them from command line?

Comment: I honestly don't know, it's not something I've tried. I presume if it can be done from the command line, it should be possible to do from code by importing cx_Freeze. Take a look at the code for it and see how it is done, it should be pretty easy to use.

Comment: Then I have the same problem as before, PyInstaller was even a little easier to understand, I think. Thank You anyway

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have already installed Pyinstaller in PYINSTALLER_PATH (you should have called the Configure.py script in the distribution for the first time), Pyinstaller generates a spec file from your main script by calling the Makespec.py. You can add some flags to generate one dir binary distribution or one file. Finally you have to call Build.py with spec file.

This is easy scriptable with a couple of system calls. Something like :

```
import os

PROJECT_NAME = "test"
PROJECT_MAIN_SCRIPT = "main_script.py"
MAKESPEC_CMD = """%s %s\Makespec.py -X -n %s -F %s""" % (PYTHON_EXECUTABLE, PYINSTALLER_PATH, PROJECT_NAME, PROJECT_MAIN_SCRIPT)
BUILD_CMD = """%s %s\Build.py %s.spec""" % (PYTHON_EXECUTABLE, PYINSTALLER_PATH, PROJECT_NAME)

os.system(MAKESPEC_CMD)
os.system(BUILD_CMD)
```

You can avoid to generate the spec file every time and hack it, adding embedded resources (i.e. xml files or configuration) and specifying some other flag. Basically this is a python file, with the definition of some dictionaries.

I don't think there is a Pyinstaller module you can use directly, but you can look at Build.py and mimic its behaviour to do the same. Build.py is the main script which does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading Pyinstaller's latest development code. There they trying to implement GUI toolkit for building executables.